# Adding redundant inequality to TDI system remains TDI

Tags: linear-programming, duality-theorems, polyhedra, integer-programming

Suppose that the polytope $P=\{x\mid Ax\leq b\}$ is totally dual integral (TDI), and that the inequality $\tilde{a}^Tx\leq \tilde{b}$ is satisfied at every point of $P$.

Does this imply that the system $\{Ax\leq b, \ \  \tilde{a}^Tx\leq \tilde{b}\}$ is TDI ?

I am not sure how to (dis)prove that. I tried to apply the definition of TDI to the new system and I don't quite see why it should be TDI. On the other hand it would seem strange that adding a redundant inequality breaks the TDI property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total dual integrality is a property of a system and not of a polyhedron.
For every rational polyhedron $P$ there exists a TDI system $Ax \leq b$ 
such that $P = \{ x\in \mathbb{R}^n\ :\ Ax \leq b\}$. You need $b$ to be integral in order to be able to deduce that $P$ is integral.

Adding a redundant inequality to a TDI system results to a TDI system.
Consider the primal problem with an integral $c$
\begin{align}
\max&.\ cx\\
s.t.\ &Ax \leq b
\end{align}

Since the Primal system before adding the redundant inequality is TDI there
exists an integral optimal solution $u'$ for the corresponding Dual Problem.

Now consider the dual problem 
\begin{align}
\max. ub &+ v \bar{b}\\
s.t. uA &= c,\ \\
v\bar{a} &=c,\\
u \geq 0,\ &v \geq 0 
\end{align}
To prove that the Primal system is TDI we have to construct an optimal
integer solution $u^*$ for the Dual problem. Notice that adding a redudant
inequality does not change the optimal value of the Primal problem. Then the solution $u^* =(u', 0)$ is a feasible optimal integral solution for the Dual.

Nevertheless adding redundant inequalities to systems which are not TDI may result to a TDI system.
The following system is clearly non TDI.
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
\leq
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
Still we can produce a TDI system for the same polyhedron by adding
a redudant inequality to obtain the TDI system
\begin{align}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
\leq
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

[This paper](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/papers/tdiops.pdf) may be useful if you want to see which operations preserve Total Dual Integrality.

Comment: Awesome! For some reason, I forgot to use strong duality to show that $(u',0)$ is still optimal. Thank you for this clear answer and for the paper!